# In Visual Studio 2019, .net Core 2.1, how do I add .net Framework assembly to the project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, project.json

I am working in Visual Studio 2019, and .net Core 2.1.1.

I am currently working on trying to get Identity Server 4's WsFederation integrated.  In the latest instructions I could find, he mentions adding System.IdentityModel to the app through the project.json.  Project.json seems to be deprecated now in .net core projects, and I am having a hell of a time figuring out how to add a freaking .net assembly to my project.  Do I really need to just copy the file into the project and reference, cause that just seems wrong.

Instructions I am using:
https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/IdentityServer-4-SharePoint-Integration-using-WS-Federation

Comment: Try adding the NuGet package for `System.IdentityModel` to the project. In Visual Studio you can find it under `Project\Manage NuGet Packages`

Comment: [System.IdentityModel](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.IdentityModel) can't be used in .net core, only .net framework

Answer (score -1):

Seems to all come back to the project type.  I had created the project with AspnetCore and so I couldn't reference any .net framework assemblies, because you can't go back once you have made that choice.  However, if you create the project specifically under the .net framework, you can move forward into the core frameworks, and hosting libraries of core.  Which then allowed me to pull in the System.IdentityModel assemblies I needed to continue forward.